# Servlet class not instantiated upon "Submit" on JSP --- Servlet instantiating error- HTTP 500 - Eclipse

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, instantiation, http-status-code-500

Getting a HTTP 500 error instantiating a server.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.expend.servlets

Following are the troubleshooting steps I have taken

1. Servlet annotation :
   @WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
   has been removed and only web.xml was tried. No use
2. class name tried - both ways:

   ```
        <servlet-class>com.expend.servlets</servlet-class>
         <servlet-class>com.servlets</servlet-class>
   ```
3. Constructor and doGet, doPost methods were made public.

The welcome JSP page is served, but does not hit the servlet when login info is entered and "Submit" clicked on JSP. Any help troubleshooting this would be appreciated.

[image: JSP PAGE]

[image: Servlet Code/Page]

[image: Web.XML code]

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: `action="LoginServlet"` instead of `action="login"`

Comment: What is the first line of  the LoginServlet.java file?  It should be;  package com.expend.servlets    By the way, what is  com.expend.java.Login ?  Why are you importing it into LoginServlet ?